# Using urllib2 for posting data, following redirects and maintaining cookies

Tags: python, urllib2

I am using `urllib2` in **Python** to post login data to a web site.

After successful login, the site redirects my request to another page. Can someone provide a simple code sample on how to do this in Python with `urllib2`? I guess I will need cookies also to be *logged in* when I get redirected to another page. Right?

Thanks a lot in advace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, get mechanize: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/
You could do this kind of stuff with just urllib2, but you will be writing tons of boilerplate code, and it will be buggy.

Then:

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open('http://somesite.com/account/signin/')

br.select_form('loginForm')    
br['username'] = 'jekyll'
br['password'] = 'bananas'
br.submit()
# At this point, you're logged in, redirected, and the 
#  br object has the cookies and all that.

br.geturl() # e.g. http://somesite.com/loggedin/
```

Then you can use the Browser object `br` and do whatever you have to do, click on links, etc. Check the samples on the mechanize site